# How to create column that can contain few parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a SQL Server table.

This table will have 4 columns.

One of these columns, `colour`, will have to be with 3 parameters (HSL).

It should look like this:

[image]

Any idea how can I implement this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need three different columns for `H,S,L`. This is basic normalisation that a column should contain  [atomic values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: Don't even think about doing this! This violates even the **first normal form** - one cell (column/row) = at most 1 value (or none) - but never more than one, single, atomic value.

Comment: Does single UID have exactly one color?   Or can a single UID have zero or more colors?

Comment: If hue, lightness and saturation are all 8-bit values then you could combine them arithmetically into a 32-bit integer, much like RGB values are commonly handled.  Stranger combinations of data can be melded into an XML column.  And, as stated by Martin Smith, stuffing multiple values into a single column is, as a rule, a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your table [**normalized**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you have to move these three values(`H`, `S`, `L`) into a new Table, something like `HSLValues`. With a foreign key to the `UID` column. then this created table should look something like:

**`HSLValues`**:

- `Id`
- `HValue`
- `SValue`
- `LValue`
- `UID` Foreign key references firsttable(UID).